# prettyPhoto: broken URL generation for Twitter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I'm using prettyPhoto plugin for a galery. It comes with FB and Twitter share buttons. However, there's a problem with updating Twitter's share URL when openening new pictures. The URL always points to the first picture opened.

It seems this is a [known bug](http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/12349/twitter-fb-like-button-generated-url-bug), has someone managed to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to get around this bug by supplying a callback for `changepicturecallback` option. Inside the callback I then remove Twitter button that was injected by prettyPhoto and initialize a new one with a proper URL.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {      
  jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    theme: 'dark_rounded',
    changepicturecallback: onPictureChanged
  });

  function onPictureChanged() {
    var twitterDiv = jQuery('.twitter');
    twitterDiv.empty();

    jQuery('<a>', {
      'class': 'twitter-share-button',
      'text': 'Tweet',
      'data-url': location.href,
      'data-count': 'none',
      'href': 'http://twitter.com/share'      
    }).appendTo(twitterDiv);    

    twttr.widgets.load();    
  }     
});
```